# How do I exclude logged-in users from this wordpress function?

Tags: wordpress, function

I'm using Wordpress Multisite. I have 3 sites in the in the network:

1. mysite.com for international audiences
2. mysite.com/uk/ for UK audiences
3. mysite.com/ie/ for Irish audiences

I want to redirect people from the .com depending on their location.
I've got some lines of code that seems to work but unfortunately, it redirects me too. I'm in Ireland so the code prevents me admining the .com. Any thoughts on how I can fix this? code below. Any help appreciated

```html
function country_geo_redirect() {
$country = getenv('HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE');
if ( $country == "GB" ) {
wp_redirect( 'https://www.website.com/uk/', 301 );
exit;
} else if ( $country == "IE" ) {
wp_redirect( 'https://www.website.com/ie/', 301 );
exit;
}
}
add_action('init', 'country_geo_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function country_geo_redirect() {

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   return;
}

$country = getenv('HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE');
if ( $country == "GB" ) {
wp_redirect( 'https://www.website.com/uk/', 301 );
exit;
} else if ( $country == "IE" ) {
wp_redirect( 'https://www.website.com/ie/', 301 );
exit;
}
}
add_action('init', 'country_geo_redirect');
```